# Cannot reproduce the datepicker example on AngularStrap

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-strap

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XwSnYV1HNYPEWwYZQ7BR?p=preview)

and I am trying to reproduce the example shown [here](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/datepicker)

I do not see the same output, what is that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify the ng-app module name and you should be able to initialize the calender in the controller. So modify the template like this in order to link AngularJS modules:

```
<html ng-app='angularjs-starter'>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
```

In controller, do:

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', ['$strap.directives']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $window, $location) {
    $scope.datepicker = {date: new Date("2012-09-01T00:00:00.000Z")};
});
```

So you will be able to see the working calender though you may need to fix the css :)

<kbd>**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/oFazQ9kUIb7a5wKSWFLb?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, The css is not the same even though it is imported correctly

Comment: @daydreamer Updated the demo. Fixed the css for you.